# Which amines show N−N coupling reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, catalysis, amines

> We add 1 equivalent of $\ce{KCN}$ followed by catalytic reduction via Lindlar's reagent $(\ce{H2}/\ce{Pt})$ to 4-chlorobenzyl chloride (**1**).
>
> [image: 1‐chloro‐4‐(chloromethyl)benzene]
>
> Verify whether the product (**P**) obtained will undergo an N−N coupling reaction with a diazonium salt or not.

According to me, it should because I find no valid reason as to why it shouldn't. The product **P** that I obtained was 4-chlorobenzylamine (**2**):

[image: 1‐(4‐chlorophenyl)methanamine]

But the book mentions that it won't. That made me wonder if there are some amines that don't participate in coupling reactions, or is it because of something else.

Comment: Please add a complete reference to the book you are referring to, and [Please do not add hyphens after colons](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3295).

Comment: Shouldn't your first line read "We add 1 equivalent of KCN to 4-chlorobenzyl chloride (1) followed by catalytic reduction via Lindlar's reagent (H2/Pt)". If so, structure 2 is missing a methylene group.

Comment: @user55119 Yes.I was trying to say that. I think after the “editing process” there might be some issues(with regards to question’s language) here and there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your book is wrong (what book is it?)

This statement from the Wikipedia page on Azo coupling [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azo_coupling) seems definitive enough:

> In alkaline media, diazonium salt can react with most primary and secondary amines that exist as a free base and produce triazene

It also includes a reaction scheme showing a secondary amine (pyrrolidine) coupling with a phenyl diazonium salt.

[image]